# How to manually add labels to matplotlib with Python

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

I am trying to manually add `labels` to my `seaborn plot`, but this is not outputting the labels

Here is what my `dataframe` looks like:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product_ID': ['20','23', '20','24','24', '24', '24', '24','24', '20'],
 'ProductNames': ['Gem','Wil', 'Gem','Wefdem','Wefdem','Wefdem', 'Wefdem', 'Wefdem', 'Wefdem','Gem']})
```

Here is my item to plot and manually add labels

```py
# It is a large dataframe, this is just a subset thats why I selected the first largest 10 with nlargest

order=df["Product_ID"].value_counts().nlargest(10).index

# again the actual dictionary is larger than this, this is just a shorter one of it
product_keys = {"20": "Gem", "23": "Wil", "24": "Wefdem"}

plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
g = sns.countplot(df["Product_ID"], order=order)
g.axes.set_title("Most popular IDs", fontsize=40)
g.axes.set_xlabel("Product IDs", fontsize=30)
g.axes.set_ylabel("Frequency count", fontsize=30)
g.tick_params(labelsize=24)

plt.legend([g], [product_keys[key] for key in order]) # <--- This does not work or shows only one label
```

Please how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [seaborn docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) state that

> order, hue_orderlists of strings, optional
>   Order to plot the categorical levels in, otherwise the levels are inferred from the data objects.

The thing to wrap your head around is that seaborn interfaces with objects from matplotlib. As such I recommend first learning matplotlib before delving into seaborn. The `countplot` function looks for an active figure which you created by `plt.figure`. The `hue` argument looks for levels in the data that are in the second column of your dataframe.

I took the liberty to make your code a bit more pythonic:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product_ID': ['20','23', '20','24','24', '24', '24', '24','24', '20'],
 'ProductNames': ['Gem','Wil', 'Gem','Wefdem','Wefdem','Wefdem', 'Wefdem', 'Wefdem', 'Wefdem','Gem']})

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt,\
seaborn as sns
order=df["Product_ID"].value_counts().nlargest(10).index

# again the actual dictionary is larger than this, this is just a shorter one of it
product_keys = {"20": "Gem", "23": "Wil", "24": "Wefdem"}
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.countplot(x = "Product_ID", data = df,\
              order = order, ax = ax,\
              hue = "ProductNames" )
ax.set_title("Most popular IDs", fontsize=40)
ax.set_xlabel("Product IDs", fontsize=30)
ax.set_ylabel("Frequency count", fontsize=30)
ax.axes.tick_params(labelsize=24)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your time @cvanelteren I appreciate the time you invested. How do I limit the number of ```labels``` to 8 as well? It is showing a lot of labels from the ```ProductNames```

Comment: I would suggest either creating a smaller df an use that or use native matplotlib functions, for more info see [here](https://matplotlib.org/). The latter allows more control than these wrappers.